# What UI Element is This?

Tags: iphone

Does anyone know if this is some sort of a styled UISegmentedControl from the Billings app?

[control http://img2.pict.com/30/ec/9e/2658558/0/screenshot20100127at9.png](http://img2.pict.com/30/ec/9e/2658558/0/screenshot20100127at9.png)

If so, how do you customize the UISegmentedControl given that there are only Plain, Bordered, and Bar styles???

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This effect can be achieved using a UISegmentedControl. While the plain style does have rounded borders, they can be spilled off the edges of the screen. Once that is done all you need are two images per segment - one for selected state and one for unselected state.

You can then respond to a valueChanged: event,
Based on the -selectedSegmentIndex, you can set the images of the segments (as needed) using the -setImage:forSegmentAtIndex: method.

Answer (score 2):

You really can't style UISegmentedControl, it's more likely to be a view with two custom buttons wired to affect each other.

Comment: I would also use two UIButton and just change the background color based on the button index.